# Does any choice of sufficient statistic and natural parameter create valid exponential family pdfs?

Tags: sufficient-statistics, exponential-family

So exponential families can be parameterized as $f(x|\theta) = h(x)e^{T(x)n(\theta)-A(n)}$.

I'm trying to understand what the conditions are on $h(x)$, $T(x)$, and $n(\theta)$ are for $f(x|\theta)$ to be a valid pdf. (I'm ignoring $A(n)$ for now, since its just a normalizing factor).

I know we need $\int_R h(x)e^{T(x)n(\theta)}dx < \infty$ overall, along with positivity, but are there any requirements on these three component functions individually?